# Is there an automatic voting mechanism in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

I've repost an [[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984879/join-unknown-number-of-lists-in-linq/14987974#14987974)] for four times for test, and each time after I post, a -1 vote appears automatically.

I'd like to get downvotes if the answer is not applicable, I'll delete it and not post it again, or maybe some comments. But it just happen like a **spooky action at a distance**, each time I repost.

So I'm wondering **is there an automatic voting mechanism in Stack Overflow**?

Comment: No, as a comment has been left against your answer *"Please stop deleting and re-adding an answer every time it gets a downvote. Instead, perhaps it's worth examining why it is being voted down"* It is being downvoted because of the quality of the answer (and possibly now because it's annoying people who can see you repeatedly posting the same unimproved answer).

Comment: @JonW: Thank you very much.

Comment: `<trolling>` Maybe you're onto something, try deleting and re-posting this question to see if it gets 12 downvotes again :D `</trolling>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no automatic voting mechanism.

Someone is simply downvoting each and every duplicate you posted, probably *because they are duplicates*.

Note that anyone with a modern browser watching a page is notified almost instantly that new answers have been posted, so they get to see your new answer very quickly.

<sup><sub>If someone flags your posts as spam, then the Community user will downvote the post on their behalf. That is *indirect*, not automatic voting.</sub></sup>.